# What are the numbers after the HTTP status codes in App Engine's dev_appserver.py logs?

Tags: google-app-engine

When I run `dev_appserver.py` locally I see messages like this:

```
INFO     2014-01-05 02:19 ... default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 793
INFO     2014-01-05 02:19 ... default: "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1253
INFO     2014-01-05 02:20 ... default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 801
...
```

What do the numbers at the end of the lines represent?  In this case 793, 1253, 801?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Following the Apache common log format convention, those numbers are the `Content-Length`s of the respective responses.

If you're curious, look in the SDK in `lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/_cplogging.py` in `access()` (~line 207).

Comment: Thanks! The comments in the source code pointed me to this apache.org link, which I found valuable too:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/logs.html#combined